# how to control different layers in html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins, styles

[webpageview(Normal) :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4lRU.png)

[webpageview(when browser minimised horizontally) :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpIMc.png)

[webpageview(when browser minimised horizontally) :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaosD.png)

CSS and HTML code i used for notice section :

```css
/*=================================Common=================*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

p {
  font-weight: 500;
}


/*========================resuable=============*/

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.box {
  padding: 1%;
}

.list-item a:link,
.list-item a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.list-item a:hover,
.list-item a:active {
  color: #4285f4;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*==============================Heading====================*/

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  word-spacing: 4px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 180%;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/*====================Button=========================*/

.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.24);
}


/*==============================NOTICE====================*/

.notice {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendor/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendor/css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css/generic.css" />
  <link href="vendor/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.3.0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css/js-image-slider.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/resources/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/resources/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/resources/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/resources/favicons/site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/resources/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/resources/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- *******************************-->
    <!--                  NOTICE        -->
    <!-- *******************************-->
    <div class="notice col span-1-of-3">
      <img src="resources/img/notice.png" alt="notice" class="notice-img">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/js/jquery.easy-ticker.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var dd = $('.vticker').easyTicker({
            direction: 'up',
            easing: 'easeInOutBack',
            speed: 'slow',
            interval: 2000,
            height: 'auto',
            visible: 7,
            mousePause: 0,
          }).data('easyTicker');
        });
      </script>
      <style>
        .notice-img {
          width: 100px;
          margin-left: 50px;
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        
        .vticker {
          background-color: #fff;
          box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(105, 105, 105, 0.2);
          width: 209.76px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          position: fixed;
        }
        
        .vticker ul {
          padding: 0;
        }
        
        .vticker li {
          border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.33);
          padding: 10px;
          font-size: 60%;
          font-weight: 500;
        }
        
        .vticker li a {
          color: #9D4949;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="vticker">
        <ul>
          <li class="list-item"><a href="resources/pdf/alumnimeet2018.pdf" target="_blank">Alumni Meet - 2018</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a href="resources/pdf/spss_brochure.pdf" target="_blank">Two Day National Workshop on SPSS dt. 27-28/Feb/18</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a href="resources/downloads/lab_file_mba_sem_iv.docx" download>Guidelines COMPUTER lab MBA Sem-IV</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a href="">Admission Open - 2018 in MBA - MSW - BBA - BCA - B.Com</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a href="http://fwld.in/hdfcbankso" target="_blank">Jobs!! Apply Online - HDFC Bank Recruitment</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a href="resources/downloads/tpg.zip" download>Summer Training Project Report Guidelines</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a href="resources/pdf/twpr.pdf" target="_blank">Training Progress Report Format</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="vendor/js/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

[used js lib](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NwiOxSmrQfD-QKR150-9Xh_R2AdjjaUp/view?usp=drivesdk)

so here i'll explain the whole problem.
i used a js news-ticker plugin and then given the news ticker a white background with a notice image on top of background layer. but everytime i minimize my browser window the news-ticker and the white background splits into two parts.
and the nearby image gets sandwiched between them. how can i fix that splitting of layers or how can i add notice image on top of news ticker so that no background will be there for splitting.
thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: one option would be to not display the ticker when the browser window is smaller than x px (use media queries to set display:none;}

Comment: I want that ticker